# undefined reference to "distorm_decode32"

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I'm using Code::Blocks and compiling with MinGW (under Windows, of course), and with the following code I get the error "undefined reference to distorm_decode32".

```
#include "distorm.h"
// ....
distorm_decode(/*...*/);
```

It seems like a linker error, right? So I went to (in CodeBlocks) **Project > Build Options > Debug (and Release too) > Linker Settings > Link Libraries > Add > distorm**

I have placed the `distorm.lib` file in `(CodeBlocks dir)/MinGW/libs/distorm.lib`, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Instead of this:

```
#include "distorm.h"
```

Use this:

```
#include <distorm.h>
```

Both `distorm.h` and `distorm.lib` must be placed in `CodeBlocks\MinGW\headers` and `CodeBlocks\MinGW\libs`.

Thanks.